# Could openframeworks udp manager only receive char[]?

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I program using openframeworks addons udpManager.

The example code in udp receiver side is like this:

```
void ofApp::update()
{
    char udpMessage[1000];
    udpConnection.Receive(udpMessage,1000);
    string message=udpMessage;
}
```

But if I want to send the byte[] (not using udp sender, using the other language), could I receive by u_int8[] or int[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes, you could. Here is how.

All you have to do is to map `udpMessage`, which is of type `char` into a `u_int8[]` or `int[]`

```
uint8_t *destinationArray = NULL;

destinationArray = (uint8_t*)&udpMessage;
```

This works because you are simply mapping the location in memory of `udpMessage`, only you are interpreting it as an array of `uint8_t`. You can use subscript operator `[]` on `destinationArray`, however, be sure to check for out-of-bounds.

Alse, be careful, as memory mapping is sensitive to type sizes. If size of `char` is different that `uint8_t` on your implementation, it will cause data to be mapped incorrectly.